# audio frequency detection in javascript

Tags: javascript, audio

is there anyway to determine the frequencies in audio? I would like to create a waveform to react to frequencies, but I am not sure where to start, I would like to create my own without having to use other pre-created one.

I know that mozilla has something similar to this, but I want something that I can use across all browsers, so is there anyway I can detect frequencies in audio through javascript code.

Comment: You can indeed. I created one but there is a problem with the CORS restrictions. http://codepen.io/www139/pen/oLrJAZ?editors=0010